# how to find the total number of months between the two dates including extra days?

Tags: java

I have a requirement where I need to find out number of months between two dates including extra days.

example:

**start date:01/01/2014**

**end date:21/02/2014**

```
LocalDate startDate = new LocalDate(startDate1);

LocalDate endDate = new LocalDate(endDate1);

PeriodType monthDay =PeriodType.yearMonthDay().withYearsRemoved();

Period difference = new Period(startDate, endDate, monthDay);

int months = difference.getMonths();

int days = difference.getDays()
```

the out put I will get is:

> months:1 days:20

but my requirement is I want get total months including that extra day.

like:1.66 months.

How to get this one in java?

Comment: Whats mean by 1.66 months? is it 1 month 66 days?

Comment: So, do you want the difference in days divided by 30?

Comment: 1.66 means the the remaining day has to converted into months.
if i divided by remaining days/30 some months having 30 day and some are 31 and February month having 28/29 day. i didn't get accurate result if like this.

Comment: I think you are wrong in your expectation. Between 01/01 and 01/02 there is one months difference, and zero days. Between 01/01 and 02/02 there is one months difference and (2 - 1 = 1) 1 day. So between 01/01 and 21/02 there is one months difference and (21 - 1 = 20) 20 days.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to say `1.66` months you need to define how long a month is. It's not always the same. If you assume that a month is 30 days long then you can solve this by using:

```
Date startDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("01/01/2014");
Date endDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("21/02/2014");
double result = (endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime()) / (1000D*60*60*24*30);
```

This gives us `1.7` and if you divide with 31 you get `1.6451612903225807`.

If you want a better (but not perfect) approximation of how long a month is you can try `365/12` which will give you `1.6767123287671233` but still this is not perfect because leap years have 366 days.

The problem though is not with the formula, but with the problem definition. Nobody in real life says "I'll be there in exactly 1.66 months" and nobody will ever ask you to convert `1.66 months` in days.

Comment: What's wierd is this should work, but I got a negative number:
     final Date startDate = new GregorianCalendar (2014, 1, 1).getTime ();
        final Date endDate = new GregorianCalendar (2014, 2, 21).getTime ();
        System.out.println ((endDate.getTime () - startDate.getTime ())
                / (float) (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30));

Comment: i can not take month always 30 days long.it may 31 or in case February
28 or 29 day will come. how can how can achieve this.

Comment: @etherous: Yes. There is a catch. `1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30` overflows. You need to start with `1000D` or `1000F`.

Comment: @shekhara You can use switch and instead of hardcoding it to 30 take number of days according to the month  and for february apply login to check for leap year as well.

Comment: @shekhara I'm confused now. Since January is 31 days, between Jan 1st and Feb 21st would be, as you said, 1 month, 20 days. But this is NOT what you originally wanted

Comment: @etherous Actually i got answer 1 month 20 day by the above logic i posted.

Comment: @Dipika your suggestion i correct solution for my problem.
thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This is my own answer, a variation on cherouvim's

```
final Date startDate = new GregorianCalendar (2014, 0, 1).getTime ();
final Date endDate = new GregorianCalendar (2014, 1, 21).getTime ();
System.out.println ((endDate.getTime () - startDate.getTime ()) / (float) (1000L * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30));
```